# Split a line at the first special character Python

Tags: python

So I have a line of text like this getting read into my program:

```
00001740 n 3 eintiteas aonán beith 003 @ 00001930 n 0000 ~ 00002137 n 0000 ~ 04424418 n 0000
```

And I want to split that in two at the first special character. Most of the time the line is split by the '@' symbol, but in some cases a different character comes up. ('~', '+', '#p', '#m', '%p', '=').

So far I have it working for the '@' character:

```
def split_pointer_part(self, line):
    self.before_at, self.after_at = line.partition('@')[::2]
    return self.before_at, self.after_at
```

How do I change this to work for the first one that shows up out of the list of special characters?

Comment: you'll need the `re` module (regexp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "00001740 n 3 eintiteas aonán beith 003 @ 00001930 n 0000 ~ 00002137 n 0000 ~ 04424418 n 0000"
>>> re.split(r'(?:#p|#m|%p|[@~+=])', line, 1)
['00001740 n 3 eintiteas aon\xc3\xa1n beith 003 ', ' 00001930 n 0000 ~ 00002137 n 0000 ~ 04424418 n 0000']
```

Comment: @JoelCornett Just realised :p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [re.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). It works like the regular split but accepts a regular expression.

Example:

```
import re
string = "00001740 n 3 eintiteas aonán beith 003 @ 00001930 n 0000 ~ 00002137 n 0000 ~      04424418 n 0000"
print(re.split(r'\@|\~|\+|\#p|\#,|\%p|\=', string))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to check if any of the special character comes up. Lets store the first special character that came up in the variable `specialChar`. You can now call `line.partition(specialChar)`.